# using zomato filter library for filtering images load from gallery

Tags: android

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ThumbnailCallback {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("NativeImageProcessor");
    }

    private Activity activity;
    private RecyclerView thumbrecyclerView;
    private ImageView placeHolderImageView;
    String ss;
    Bitmap thumbImage;;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ss = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        activity = this;
        initUIWidgets();



    }

    private void initUIWidgets() {
        thumbrecyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.thumbnails);
        placeHolderImageView =  findViewById(R.id.place_holder_imageview);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(ss));
            placeHolderImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        initHorizontalList();
    }

    private void initHorizontalList() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
        thumbrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        thumbrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        bindDataToAdapter();
    }

    private void bindDataToAdapter() {
        final Context context = this.getApplication();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                thumbImage = null;
                try {
                    thumbImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(ss));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ThumbnailItem t1 = new ThumbnailItem();
                ThumbnailItem t2 = new ThumbnailItem();
                ThumbnailItem t3 = new ThumbnailItem();
                ThumbnailItem t4 = new ThumbnailItem();
                ThumbnailItem t5 = new ThumbnailItem();
                ThumbnailItem t6 = new ThumbnailItem();

                t1.image = thumbImage;
                t2.image = thumbImage;
                t3.image = thumbImage;
                t4.image = thumbImage;
                t5.image = thumbImage;
                t6.image = thumbImage;
                ThumbnailsManager.clearThumbs();
                ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(t1); // Original Image

                t2.filter = SampleFilters.getStarLitFilter();
                ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(t2);

                t3.filter = SampleFilters.getBlueMessFilter();
                ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(t3);

                t4.filter = SampleFilters.getAweStruckVibeFilter();
                ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(t4);

                t5.filter = SampleFilters.getLimeStutterFilter();
                ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(t5);

                t6.filter = SampleFilters.getNightWhisperFilter();
                ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(t6);

                List<ThumbnailItem> thumbs = ThumbnailsManager.processThumbs(context);

                ThumbnailsAdapter adapter = new ThumbnailsAdapter(thumbs, (ThumbnailCallback) activity);
                thumbrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        handler.post(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailClick(Filter filter) {

        placeHolderImageView.setImageBitmap(filter.processFilter(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.photo), 640, 640, false)));
    }
}

//// Adapter class
public class ThumbnailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "THUMBNAILS_ADAPTER";
    private static int lastPosition = -1;
    private ThumbnailCallback thumbnailCallback;
    private List<ThumbnailItem> dataSet;

    public ThumbnailsAdapter(List<ThumbnailItem> dataSet, ThumbnailCallback thumbnailCallback) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Thumbnails Adapter has " + dataSet.size() + " items");
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
        this.thumbnailCallback = thumbnailCallback;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        Log.v(TAG, "On Create View Holder Called");
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.list_thumbnail_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ThumbnailsViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        final ThumbnailItem thumbnailItem = dataSet.get(i);
        Log.v(TAG, "On Bind View Called");
        ThumbnailsViewHolder thumbnailsViewHolder = (ThumbnailsViewHolder) holder;
        thumbnailsViewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumbnailItem.image);
        thumbnailsViewHolder.thumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
        setAnimation(thumbnailsViewHolder.thumbnail, i);
        thumbnailsViewHolder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (lastPosition != i) {
                    thumbnailCallback.onThumbnailClick(thumbnailItem.filter);
                    lastPosition = i;
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        {
            //ViewHelper.setAlpha(viewToAnimate, .0f);
            //com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(viewToAnimate).alpha(1).setDuration(250).start();
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public static class ThumbnailsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public ThumbnailsViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.thumbnail =  v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using zomato library on github https://github.com/Zomato/AndroidPhotoFilters. When i implement this library in my app, its working but the problem is, when i click on the thumbnail(filter images see in snapshot) its gets crash and not apply filter on image(big image view above from filter images), the image in imageview i have been loaded from gallery and i want to apply thumbnail(filter image) on the loaded image. You can check the full library on above link but problem appear to me in onthumbnailClick methode.. Can anyone help me please...Thanks

```
 @Override
public void onThumbnailClick(Filter filter) {
    image_view =  findViewById(R.id.place_holder_ImageView);
    Bitmap abc = filter.processFilter(testbitmap);
    image_view.setImageBitmap(abc);

}
```

// Error is

```
10-20 15:05:06.757 10261-10261/com.example.muhammadmehran.framedemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.muhammadmehran.framedemo, PID: 10261
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "content://media/external/images/media/26568"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at com.example.muhammadmehran.framedemo.MainActivity.onThumbnailClick(MainActivity.java:128)
    at com.example.muhammadmehran.framedemo.ThumbnailsAdapter$1.onClick(ThumbnailsAdapter.java:49)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21162)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

//snapshot is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfWMS.png)

Comment: Can you post the code of the **MainActivity** and the **ThumbnailsAdapter**?

Comment: @Abdul Wadood check the code... Try ur best thanks

Comment: Can you upload the repo on Github and post that link? If that is possible. :)